# Uploading resources to jsFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I just found out about jsFIddle, seems great. Problem is their documentation is very very basic.
I put my code (HTML/JS/Css) in the right text boxes, and the result seems okay, only non of the images are there, obviously.

Is there a way to upload them to my jsFiddle account, or do I have to upload them somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to upload your resources somewhere on the net.